# Flush a RxJs Subject

Tags: javascript, rxjs, aws-lambda

I want to create a subject with a bufferTime pipe.
e.g.

```
subject.pipe(bufferTime(1000, null, this._bufferSize),
  filter((v, i) => {
    return v.length !== 0;
  })
)
```

After using this subject and finishing the work I'd like for the user to call the onComplete / new method that will flush the remaining contents of the stream.

Since this is time based I could wait for the stream to flush itself, but as I'm using AWS Lambda runtime is money.

Is there a simple way to implement a flush?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`takeUntil`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeUntil) operator:

```
const subject = new Subject();
const complete = new Subject();
const BUFFER_SIZE = 10;

subject
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(complete),
    bufferTime(1000, null, BUFFER_SIZE),
  )
  .subscribe(buffer => {
    console.log(Date.now(), buffer);
  });
```

I use another `Subject` called `complete` that is used for completing the Observable and consequently flushing the buffer in `bufferTime`.

See working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ihjbxb